# Python Blender .Blend Export and Back-Link Script (persistent handler problem)

Tags: python, export, collections, append

I'm trying to create a blender script that will move selected objects to a new .blend file and then link those specific objects back to the original file.

This would be extremely useful to me and my workflow. Since Blend files can get kind of cluttered with objects and I figured it would be really nice to be able to partition them off to different files.

I've tried the following code but I have had problems with handler methods. For some reason I can't get the first .Blend file to link the objects.

...
I apologize in advance since I am new to python, and blender scripts...

Here's the code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


filep = bpy.data.filepath

#Moves chosen objects to a collection 
collection = bpy.data.collections.new( "link" )
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for coll in obj.users_collection:
            # Unlink the object
            coll.objects.unlink(obj)
    collection.objects.link( obj )
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[collection.name]

bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=filep)



#Creates a New File with isolated objects...
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile('INVOKE_AREA')

for c in bpy.data.collections:
    if c.name != collection.name:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(c)

for a in bpy.data.objects:
    f = False
    for b in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if a == b:
            f = True 
    if f == False:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(a, do_unlink=True)
    

#[THE PROBLEM-]: LINKING Handler: supposed to link objects back to Main File..
name = collection.name
h = bpy.data.filepath
g = bpy.path.basename
@persistent
def load_handler():
    bpy.ops.wm.link(directory= h + "/Collection/", filepath= g, filename=name)

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)

#open original file
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=filep)
```